# How do ACLs influence ls / stat() results?

Tags: linux, bash, posix, acl

Why would a directory show `drwxrwxr-x+` when there is no group-writable bit?

Let's give one extra user (john) `rwx` permission on a directory, like so:

```
$ mkdir logfiles
$ setfacl -m user:john:rwx logfiles
$ getfacl -ce logfiles
user::rwx
user:john:rwx                   #effective:rwx
group::r-x                      #effective:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

That's just how I want things, and john now has access equivalent to the directory owner. However,

```
$ ls -ld logfiles
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 bob users 4096 Mar  6 22:38 logfiles

$ find -perm +020 -ls
  8197    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 bob      users        4096 Mar  6 22:38 ./logfiles
```

No group has write permission, but the output of ls and the matching result from find would suggest otherwise. This is coming directly from the st_mode field of the lstat(2) system call; why is the `S_IWGRP` bit being set?

Comment: The group-write bit must have been set when you created the directory. What is your `umask`?

Comment: Nope, umask is 022, perms before setfacl are 755 (see also getfacl output in the example - `group::r-x`). Do you get a different result?

Comment: No, I get the same result as you, with an xfs filesystem. I don't know why!

Answer (score 2):

Once POSIX ACLs is activated for a given file or directory. The group class permission mode is no longer the group permission, it is in fact the mask ACL entry (not related to `umask`). So now because your file has POSIX ACL extensions (as can be seen by the `+` suffix in `ls -l`), that `rwx` shown by ls, stat and find is not actually the group class permission mode anymore. Modifying the group class permission mode with `chmod` also only changes the mask, and does not change the real group class permission mode. This means the only way for you to change the group class permission mode is by using `setfacl`.

The mask ACL entry appears to be the maximum possible permissions for all ACL entries that is "assigned" the group class. This includes named users, named groups and the owning group. It does not include the owning user and the other classes. This can limit the assigned permissions for any named user, named group or the owning group. For maximum flexibility, set the mask to `rwx`, then set named user, named group and owning group permissions at your discretion. This will all work for things like `cd`, `ls` and other stuff. However this does mean when using `ls`, or `stat`.. etc, they will all show `rwx` for the group class, even though that is not true.

Why is this mask here? What purpose does it solve? It seems that the mask was here for backwards compatibility with programs that don't understand POSIX ACLs. What happens if a program that doesn't understand POSIX ACLs and sees `rwx` in the group class (and in reality it's actually the mask), does it succeed in accessing the directory/file or not? (I do not know the answer to this question). I think this is really weird quirk, and should probably be removed. But that's how POSIX ACLs work.

Answer (score 1):

Here may lie your answer --  ACL propagation:

```
http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/
```

Some filesytems allow it as a mount option.  I do not know what filesystem you have, so this may be a poor answer.

Comment: That doc does address my question, sort of, in section "Access ACL Example". I am no less confused though, because its example shows `chmod g-w` and `chmod g+w` being used to edit the mask entry, not the group.

Comment: I think you may have missed the idea.  ACL's get created on new files, based on the acls of the parent directory, or some some cases elsewhere.  Your chmod has not much to do with it. setfacl and getfacl   generally are the ACL interface.

Comment: I was referring to the specific chmod examples given in "Access ACL Example" from your answer. Can you explain why the group writeable bit behaves this way? I probably have missed the idea, hence this whole question :)

Comment: @Phil it appears the way the mask was implemented was for backwards compatibility for non POSIX ACL programs, something that seems like a historical artifact that is no longer necessary, but has not been changed.